# In Java inner class final static works without constructor only

Tags: java

I have an inner class which looks like this:

```
class Inner {
    final static String ok = "something";
    final static String nok = new String("something");
}
```

A compile time error occurs in the second declaration but not in the first one.
Seems as if non-static inner classes not allow explicit invocation of constructor. Also static initializer is not allowed.

Can anyone explain the background?

Comment: See also this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156543/constants-and-inner-classes

Answer (score 0):

If you make your inner class static it would work:

```
public class Outer {

   static class Inner {
       final static String ok = "something";
       //Now this is ok also
       final static String nok = new String("something");
       }
}
```

You must explicitly declare inner class to be static if you want to allow explicit invocation of a constructor.This is because inner class is not explicitly or implicitly declared static and your job is to mark it as such if you want to use constructor invocation inside it.